# Parse string in C# using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Need to parse:

```
/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/5678/providers/BlaBlaBla/workspaces/BluBluBlu
```

and extract the variables:

- 1234
- 5678
- BlaBlaBla
- BluBluBlu

How can I do it in a clean way using C# and regular expressions?

Comment: Why not just split by '/' rather than using regex? Don't get me wrong, I love regex, but I'm just curious.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'd rather do it in a single line of code if possible.

Comment: as opposed to...? Doing a match with Regex still won't get you it "in one line"? You'll still need to reference variables by their index/capture index whichever solution you use.

Comment: Are the variables positional or of a certain identifiable type or construct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not intended as answer, but to future readers (I got bored)

**Regex**

```
return Regex.Matches(input, @"^(?:/[^/]*/([^/]*))+")[0]
            .Groups[1]
            .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
```

**regexCompiled**

```
private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:/[^/]*/([^/]*))+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
...

return regex.Matches(input)[0]
            .Groups[1]
            .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
```

**Split**

```
return input.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Skip(1)
            .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)
            .ToArray();
```

**Unsafe**

```
var list = new List<string>();
var result = string.Empty;

fixed (char* pInput = input)
{
   var plen = pInput + input.Length;
   var toggle = true;

   for (var p = pInput; p < plen; p++)
   {
      if (*p == '/')
      {       
         if (result.Length > 0)
            list.Add(result);
         toggle = !toggle;
         result = string.Empty;
         continue;
      }
      if (toggle)
         result += *p;
   }
}
list.Add(result);
return list.ToArray();
```

---

## Benchmarks

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9
Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3901 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Results**

```
--- Random characters -------------------------------------------------------
| Value         |  Average |  Fastest |   Cycles | Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 1 -------------------------------------------------- Time 0.152 ---
| unsafe        | 2.131 µs | 1.461 µs | 10.567 K | 0.000 B | Pass | 78.42 % |
| split         | 3.874 µs | 2.922 µs | 16.804 K | 0.000 B | Pass | 60.76 % |
| regexCompiled | 7.313 µs | 5.845 µs | 29.310 K | 0.000 B | Pass | 25.93 % |
| regex         | 9.873 µs | 7.891 µs | 37.800 K | 0.000 B | Base |  0.00 % |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Summary**

Tested a massive 1,000,000 times each on diffrent string combinations that reflect the original pattern.

Unsafe is jsut ridiculous and should not be used, Regex is neat and tidy, split is not too unreadable either. As epected split is faster.

However, regex is not as slow as i thought it would be. In the end, its comes down to persoanl perfence and your code reviewer.

**Update**

As *sln* rightly mentioned in a comment, regex should be compiled for this to be a good benchmark. Note i left out the suggest of leaving out the `.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();` basically just to leave the result an array of string to keep them all the same.

The compilation to IL gives regex a good performance boost.

***Disclaimer**, i have nothing against regex and use it all the time*

Comment: Not really the way to benchmark regex. It should always be precompiled. Also, there is only ever 1 match, that is usually the case (and only use) for capture collection. Boiled down, it's this `var rx = new Regex( @"^(?:/[^/]*/([^/]*))+");
    return rx.Match(input) 
       .Groups[1]
       .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
       .Select(m => m.Value)
       .ToArray();` To be clear, the regex is defined _outside_ the scope of the benchmark iteration.

Comment: @sln updated, i was curious myself, seems to give about 25% boost in this situation which isnt shabby at all

Comment: If you're interested in regex benchmarking, take a look at this.
This software uses a built in engine for Perl, PCRE, Java style regex.
[RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) benchmark suite
[b1](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b1.jpg)
[b2](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b2.jpg)
[b3](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b3.jpg)l
[b4](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b4.jpg)
The screenshots don't show it but all benches show matches per second.
It installs as a free trial version, but I can give you a registration key if interrested.

Comment: @sln looks pretty neat, ill give it a look today, i have a regex adventure myself to sort

Answer (score 4):

single line of code

```
var bits = noodly.Split('/');
```

Comment: `bits.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0);` maybe... or actually `.Skip(1).Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

If still need regex and if positional, like every other one, you could use a *Capture Collection* with this regex.

`^(?:/[^/]*/([^/]*))+`

The items are in group 1's capture collection.